# Ruby getting started guide: uninitialized constant PostsController::Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post

I've done the ruby getting started guide a few times over and I always end up with the same result.
[Guids](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

```
NameError in PostsController#index
 uninitialized constant PostsController::Posts
```

Extracted source (around line #21):

```
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

---

```
def index
    @posts = Posts.all
end

def edit
```

`Rails.root: C:/RailsTesting/blog`

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:21:in `index'
Request

Out of frustration/desperation, I copied all of the files from the actual code supplied by the tutorial with no avail, please help.

Here's my `index`

```
<h1>Hello, Rails!</h1>
<%= link_to "My Blog", controller: "posts" %>

<%= link_to 'New post', new_post_path %>


<table>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Text</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<tr>
<td><%= post.title %></td>
<td><%= post.text %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post_path(post),
                method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</tr>
```

...

Here is my `posts_controller`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))

    if @post.save
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def index
    @posts = Posts.all
end

def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy

    redirect_to posts_path
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
    end

  end
```

Comment: You should state a clear question somewhere in your post, preferably at the top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `index` method has the `Post` class written in plural. Change it to `Post.all`

Comment: Okay, this makes sense now. I've changed it however I am getting another error now in return.  'SyntaxError in PostsController#index
C:/RailsTesting/blog/app/models/post.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tDOT3, expecting ']' [...] ^

Extracted source (around line #21):
19
20
21
22
23
24
          

 def index
    @posts = Post.all
 end

 def edit
'

Answer (score 0):

Modify your index action as:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

Here `Post` is the model from where you are get all posts.